# How can I define a section about formulas and calculations in my documentation

Tags: word-form

I'm writing a documentation for a program I wrote, and one section is about the mathematical formulas and calculations I used. I want to create a different section for this but cannot come up with the word to describe this section.

The documentation is for a program that is embedded into Autodesk Inventor to build high pressure vessels and process columns. For some pieces of the code there are some trigonometric problems and they are solved. In the code I refer to the formula or calculation section where the calculation is explained based on sketches.

Is it possible to put this into one word? **Formulas** is an option, but something tells me there is a better word out there to use.

Answer (score 1):

Without the context which would be provided by seeing the rest of your documentation (or at least the other headings) it's quite difficult to suggest the most appropriate section/heading description to use, but what about something like `Mathematical Background`? You could replace "Background" with "Summary", "Overview", "Explanation" or maybe even "Basis" or "Justification" if that seems more appropriate.

Comment: +1.  "Mathematical notes" would also work.